# Adaptive Biasing Force Simulations in NAMD

Tags: molecular-dynamics, free-energy, binding-energy

I have performed an ABF simulation to investigate the binding of a small molecule with a 2D surface using NAMD. The initial simulation was for a scan window of 3 to 15 angstroms of z-projected distance between the small molecule and the 2D surface. However, upon analyzing the data, I observed that the sampling between the region 7-15 angstrom were significantly lower when compared to the 3-7 angstrom region. Thus, I performed an another ABF run between 7 and 15 angstroms. Is there a way I can combine these two data to generate the full 3-15 scan range?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but have you figured this out now? Please update us! Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer?

Comment: I figured out the answer.

Comment: Do you want to write a self-answer?